# Hide App name and it's bar

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been trying to remove this bar (cant hotlink images, yet, check next link):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bACj.png

But I can't achieve it.

Tried the following:

Added into manifest the following:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoActionBar"
```

But resulted as crash. Probably because I don't have this "Theme". I can't find out what should I write here.

Also tried to remove manually on each Fragment by Graphical Layout, selecting "No action bar", and it doesn't show up on the "preview" but it's shown in the app, probably because its the wrong place to configure it.

Note that it's with fragments. I searched about doing it by code, but I just found options to do it for activities.

So, my question is: How can I hide the App Action bar?

Edit:

## SOLVED

On my code, I've this:

```
final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

So, just added:

```
bar.hide();
```

And everything is working. Even if the tabs names aren't shown, the navigation still works (Swaping right and left for swapping fragments.)

Comment: Also note, that I'm testing it under 4.2 envoirment, and included android support library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Comment: Wow, this is working like charm. It even solved my second problem, wanted to hide the "tabs" names. I'm going to edit my main question, so every1 can see the solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. Marked this as resolved so people also know that this is the correct solution. The check box under the upvote box.